# Circles in the plane

Tags: geometry

There is a result about tangent circles in plane given a rational $\frac{p}{q}$ and its corresponding circle of radius $\frac{1}{p^2}$ (I think this a problem from $\text{Complex Analysis}-\operatorname{E}$. Stein but not sure). The spirit of the problem show that for every rational $\frac{p}{q}$ in the $x$-axis, there is a circle tangent to the $x$-axis with center at some $(\frac{p}{q},x)$ coordinate (and some circles are tangent to another one or disjoint), so my question is as follows:

Is it true that for every $r\in\mathbb{R}$, there is a circle with center at $(r,y)$ for some $y$, such that every two circles are disjoint?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_circle

Comment: the usual axiom of choice method does not work here. I would bet your task is impossible, but it might be difficult to prove that. Where did you get the problem?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the link xD, about where did I get the problem... It occurred to me.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by the usual AC method? Cheers

Comment: Compared to the Ford circle arrangement, you are dropping the requirement to be tangential to the $x$ axis, right? While I think Ford circles would leave no space for circles at irrational coordinates, I wonder whether making good use of the second dimension can somehow make this possible again. Interesting!

Comment: I mean, I'll still be happy if there is a solution where some circles are allowed to be tangent. Thanks!